# Is it possible to gather the percent of who gets each email from a random split and put in a DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

Right now I am trying to create a report that gathers as much info i can get from journeys and would like to know if its possible to do it with the percent of random splits. We have been using the update contact feat to update the DE with the info we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your journey has seperate emails on each path of your random decision split, you could use SQL to select the email activities from the JourneyActivity data view, then join onto the Sent data view to get all the recipients for each send job.

Note that JobIDs will change if the email activity is republished, so consider using the email Name in your query if you’re likely to update your journey emails frequently.